# Objective programming in python, why do I initialize attribute to "none"?

Tags: python-3.x, class, init

I am new to python. I found this block of code from the web. Notice he set index=None, domain=None within in the init method. Why do I need to declare the class attribute as "None"?

```
class gridPoint: 
  def __init__(self, index=None, domain=None):
    self.hv = [] # hierarchical value
    self.fv = [] # function value
    if index is None:
      self.pos = [] # position of grid point
    else:
      self.pos = self.pointPosition(index, domain)

  def pointPosition(self, index, domain=None):
    coord = list()
    if domain is None:
      for i in range(len(index)/2):
        coord.append(index[2*i+1]/2.**index[2*i])
    else:
      for i in range(len(index)/2):
        coord.append((domain[i][1] - domain[i][0]) \
                    *index[2*i+1] / 2.**index[2*i] + domain[i][0])
    return coord

  def printPoint(self):
    if self.pos is []:
      pass
    else:
      out = ""
      for i in range(len(self.pos)):
        out += str(self.pos[i]) + "\t"
      print (out)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use whatever values you want for default parameter, it doesn't have to be `None`. `None` is used conventionally in this case to provide default behavior that is slightly different than when those methods are invoked with arguments, because you should not use mutable default values like empty lists.

Answer (score 0):

He is setting those variables as optional (or the same, parameters with default values). That means if yout don't provide a value for them (for example using `a = gridPoint()`, init method will automatically consider `None` for both of them.

If any of them hadn't `=None` you will be forced to define gridPoint and passing that variable to the class.

You need them to use `if index is None` for example. Setting default values allows you (in this particular code) to avoid error of undefined variable.